# UnityContainer: what is default lifetimemanager

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I use Web API 2 and here is configuration of my unity container (i configure my rabbitmq dependencies):

```
container.RegisterInstance(new ConnectionFactory {
    Uri = AppSettings.RmqConnectionString
});

container.RegisterType<IConnection, AutorecoveringConnection>(
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ConnectionFactory), "tm.resource-server.api"),
    new InjectionMethod("Init")
);
```

Right now i can't figure out, what's the **default lifetime** of this dependencies?

What time they would be created or resolve already existing instances.

Should i use my own lifetimemanager or use already existing (PerThreadLifetimeManager for example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `RegisterInstance`'s default lifetime is `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`
2. `RegisterType`'s default lifetime is `TransientLifetimeManager`